# ReactNative Flatlist onEndReached not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im trying to call a function on `onEndReached` of a FlatList but it's not working.

I'm calling the `this.state.pageNo` at the end and it's not updating. I want to use this logic later in infinite scroll but not able to get it working now.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Alert
  } from "react-native";

 class InfiniteScrollRedux extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: false,
        pageNo: 1,
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: "Name01" },
            { id: 2, name: "Name02" },
            { id: 3, name: "Name03" },
            { id: 4, name: "Name04" },
            { id: 5, name: "Name05" },
            { id: 6, name: "Name06" }
        ]
    };
}

myFunction = () => {
    this.setState({ pageNo: this.state.pageNo++ });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View style={mystyle.mainCard}>
                        <Text style={mystyle.titleText}> {item.id} </Text>
                        <View style={{ marginTop: 200 }} />
                        <Text style={mystyle.nameText}> {item.name} </Text>
                    </View>
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                onEndReached={this.myFunction}
                onEndThreshold={0}
            />
            <Text style={{ margin: 20, padding: 20, fontSize: 20 }}>
                {this.state.pageNo}
            </Text>
        </View>
      );
   }
}

const mystyle = StyleSheet.create({
 mainCard: {
    backgroundColor: "#2F4F4F",
    marginBottom: 1,
    padding: 5
},
titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#F0FFFF"
},
nameText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#F0FFFF"
 }
 });

 export default InfiniteScrollRedux;
```

Comment: I copied your code and run it and it worked fine , no issue with your code
keep in mind `onEndReached` called only once for set of data

Comment: @Ali .. `onEndReached called only once for set of data` .. thanks.

Comment: I found answer here , I initially tried all solutions given in github comments nothing worked, but finally check this answer which worked for me. Hope it will work for other too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740770/react-native-flatlist-pagination-not-working-onendreached-doesnt-fired/48747461#48747461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are looking for in FlatList is [onEndReachedThreshold](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/flatlist.md#onendreachedthreshold) instead of onEndThreshold.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the problem was with nativebase `<Content>`. It was creating problems when `<FlatList>` was used inside it. Solution :

```
<Content
  style={{flex: 1}}
  contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} // important!
>
```

Source : https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1736

Comment: If because of some weird requirement, you have `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` then also applying the same thing (i.e. `contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}`) to ScrollView works.

Answer (score 14):

There is an issue for that here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14312. Looks like a lot of people are experiencing the same. There is a suggestion to change the `onEndReachedThreshold` to value bigger that 0, for example: 0.3.

Answer (score 4):

I was wrestling with an issue on RN 0.72.3 (and most likely older versions would have a similar issue) with FlatList not reliably calling onEndReached.  Items are loaded in via fetch calls to an external server.

I eventually found out that attempting to render the FlatList without items loaded in could cause something to break and the FlatList never calls onEndReached, even after items do load in and the component seemingly re-renders.  If I set a conditional render to only render the FlatList if my `items` variable was set and had data, it would work 100%.  Instead of relying on React to re-render components on state changes, I would only render the FlatList if `items` had actually been populated with data.

I've also applied other solutions like using `flex: 1` on containers but this seemed to be the final fix to get the FlatList to work correctly.

This was puzzling in my case because the list would eventually load if I navigated to another screen and back but if the app hadn't loaded in items before yet, it would get stuck and onEndReached wouldn't be called.  So it seemed to be "random" but eventually narrowed it down to this circumstance.

The following pseudocode may help illustrate the correct way to implement FlatList:

```
const Catalog = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  
  // Use this function for the initial load and subsequent loads from FlatList
  async function loadItems() {
    const request = await fetch(...);
    const results = await request.json();
    // Retrieve results, merge into our component's state
    setItems(items => [...items, ...results.items])
    setPage(p => p+1);
  }

  // On first render, do an initial load of items from an external server
  useEffect(() => {
    loadItems();
  }, []);
  
  // You could return from a conditional statement if we find items.length === 0
  if (!items.length) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* Or you could conditionally render FlatList only when items has a length -- use a double negation so we don't accidentally print a 0 */}
      { !!items.length && <FlatList items={items} ... /> }
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I spent days on this, you are my hero!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!  I have a couple of libraries sitting in front of my FlatList implementation like apollo client/graphql, auth libraries, stack navigators, etc. so I was worried this might have only applied to my particular setup but I'm glad it's a more general solution!  Also I realized my pseudocode was kinda bad--my real version is a lot more convoluted so I quickly wrote a simpler version--but I just cleaned it up a bit.  I'm glad you were able to get the gist of it though!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: Fixed my issue!  Thank you! A side effect is that the onEndReached is called immediately when shown.  I am guessing because it cannot calculate the height of each item, so then when new items get added, it doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should make sure that your `onEndReached` listens to your `onMomentumScrollBegin` and `onMomentumScrollEnd` props of `FlatList`. Another important thing is `distanceFromEnd` param of `onEndReached` prop of `FaltList`. So you can use it as follows:

```
          onMomentumScrollBegin={() => this.setState({ scrollBegin: true })}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={() => this.setState({ scrollBegin: false })}
          onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) =>
            distanceFromEnd<=0.5&&
            this.state.scrollBegin &&
            this.onEndReached()
          }
```

And then you can define your `onEndReached` function, which will work as needed.

Hope this will help someone to save time on this.

Comment: `onMomentumScrollBegin` and `onMomentumScrollEnd` trigger in my case, but `onEndReached` won't trigger at all.

Answer (score 1):

Got stuck with this issue for a long time. I think `React` is having confusions in calculating the screen height vs the container height.
So the best thing we can do is to increase the `onEndReachedThreshold` value to something higher than `0` to some `0.2, 0.4` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing one more reason why it wasn't working on my side. My FlatList was inside a ScrollView which was not letting the FlatList know that it has reached end. I moved my FlatList out of the ScrollView and it started to work again!

Answer (score 0):

for improving onEndReached performance
I suggest to provide exact height to contentContainerStyle
for example :

```
contentContainerStyle={{ height : items.length * itemHeight }}
```

Comment: It's not the same thing. `height` is calculated in pixel, whereas `items.length` is the number of items

Comment: @TeraMind sorry I forgot to add itemHeight , I fixed it