# React Native how to use FlatList inside nativebase Tabs onEndReach keep fire non-stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm new to react native so i use some component from 3rd party library and try to use react native component as possible.

ReactNative: 0.54
NativeBase: 2.3.10
....

i had problem with FlatList inside Tabs from Nativebase base on scrollView

1. onEndReachedThreshold not working correctly as Doc say `0.5` will trigger haft way scroll of item but when i set 0.5 it not trigger haft way to last item it wait until scroll to last item and it trigger onEndReach.
2. i had problem with onEndReach if i use ListFooterComponent to render loading when data not delivery it keep firing onEndReach non-stop.

here is my code

check props and init state

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const { params } = nextProps.navigation.state;
    const getCategoryId = params ? params.categoryId : 7;
    const getCategoryIndex = params ? params.categoryIndex : 0;
    return {
      categoryId: getCategoryId,
      categoryIndex: getCategoryIndex,
    };
  }
  state = {
    loadCategoryTab: { data: [] },
    loadProduct: {},
    storeExistId: [],
    loading: false,
    refreshing: false,
  }
```

loadCategory

```
 componentDidMount() { this.onLoadCategory(); }
  onLoadCategory = () => {
    axios.get(CATEGORY_API)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ loadCategoryTab: res.data }, () => {
          setTimeout(() => { this.tabIndex.goToPage(this.state.categoryIndex); });
        });
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Check onChange event when Tabs is swip or click

```
  onScrollChange = () => {
    const targetId = this.tabClick.props.id;
    this.setState({ categoryId: targetId });
    if (this.state.storeExistId.indexOf(targetId) === -1) {
      this.loadProductItem(targetId);
    }
  }
  loadProductItem = (id) => {
    axios.get(`${PRODUCT_API}/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        /*
        const {
          current_page,
          last_page,
          next_page_url,
        } = res.data;
        */
        this.setState({
          loadProduct: { ...this.state.loadProduct, [id]: res.data },
          storeExistId: this.state.storeExistId.concat(id),
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

loadMoreProduct when onEndReach is trigger

```
  loadMoreProductItem = () => {
    const { categoryId } = this.state;
    const product = has.call(this.state.loadProduct, categoryId)
      && this.state.loadProduct[categoryId];
    if (product.current_page !== product.last_page) {
      axios.get(product.next_page_url)
        .then((res) => {
          const {
            data,
            current_page,
            last_page,
            next_page_url,
          } = res.data;
          const loadProduct = { ...this.state.loadProduct };
          loadProduct[categoryId].data = product.data.concat(data);
          loadProduct[categoryId].current_page = current_page;
          loadProduct[categoryId].last_page = last_page;
          loadProduct[categoryId].next_page_url = next_page_url;
          this.setState({ loadProduct, loading: !this.state.loading });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    } else {
      this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
    }
  }
```

render()

```
      render() {
        const { loadCategoryTab, loadProduct } = this.state;
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
          <Container>
            <Tabs
              // NB 2.3.10 not fix yet need to use `ref` to replace `initialPage`
              ref={(component) => { this.tabIndex = component; }}
              // initialPage={categoryIndex}
              renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab tabsContainerStyle={styles.tabBackground} />}
              onChangeTab={this.onScrollChange}
              // tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 2 }}
            >
              {
                loadCategoryTab.data.length > 0 &&
                loadCategoryTab.data.map((parentItem) => {
                  const { id, name } = parentItem;
                  const dataItem = has.call(loadProduct, id) ? loadProduct[id].data : [];
                  return (
                    <Tab
                      key={id}
                      id={id}
                      ref={(tabClick) => { this.tabClick = tabClick; }}
                      heading={name}
                      tabStyle={styles.tabBackground}
                      activeTabStyle={styles.tabBackground}
                      textStyle={{ color: '#e1e4e8' }}
                      activeTextStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
                    >
                      <FlatList
                        data={dataItem}
                        keyExtractor={subItem => String(subItem.prod_id)}
                        ListEmptyComponent={this.onFirstLoad}
                        // ListFooterComponent={this.onFooterLoad}
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                        onEndReached={() => {
                            this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading }, this.loadMoreProductItem);
                        }}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                          const productItems = {
                            item,
                            navigation,
                          };
                          return (
                            <ProductItems {...productItems} />
                          );
                        }}
                      />
// this OnLoadFooter is my tempory show loading without ListFooterComponent but i don't want to show loading outside FlatList hope i will get a help soon
                      <OnLoadFooter loading={this.state.loading} style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }} />
                    </Tab>
                  );
                })
              }
            </Tabs>
          </Container>
        );
      }
```

Loading Component

```
function OnLoadFooter(props) {
  if (props.loading) return <Spinner style={{ height: 50, paddingVertical: 10 }} />;
  return null;
}
```

Let me explain my process

- init CategoryId and CategoIndex for Tabs active
- after axios fire will get all category and render Tab item because nativebase Tabs bug when initailPage bigger than 0 it show blank page and i use ref trigger it when category complete load when this.tabIndex.goToPage is trigger it call onChange
- onChage event start to check if tabClick Ref exist in StoreExistId that save category when they click if true we load product else we do nothing. i need ref in this because React state is async making my product fire loading duplicate data for 1st time so Ref come in to fix this.
- when scroll down to last item it will loadMoreProduct by paginate on API
- my data in state like below

  `StoreExistId: [1,2,3,4]
  loadProduct: {
  1: {data: [.....]},
  2: {data: [.....]},
  etc....
  }`

Thank in advanced

Comment: you may be facing this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6002.

Comment: @akhilxavier i see someone mention about set fixed height but i dunno where should i set it because my item is render base on Item from Api.

Answer (score 1):

Some of NativeBase components use scrollView inside. I guess it could be ScrollableTab component which uses ScrollView? You should not use FlatList inside ScrollView, onReachEnd will not work then.

Comment: if i don't use Flatlist what can i use to get Scroll ?example like Twitter app it has Tabs and Data under that tab and scroll to bottom to load more data.

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, solution is to use `<FlatList>` inside `<Content>` . For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305517/8858217